# AxiosError with Get Method give me 404 Error Page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, backend, mern

When I request data from Mongoose, it shows me an error and tells me that the page does not exist, knowing that I tested the back-end in Postman and it succeeded. I also tested the react by fetching data from an external link and it succeeded. I do not know what the problem is?!

I try with this code

This is my back-end code

```
const app = require("./app");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/get-now";
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log(`database connected`))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`the server is ${port}`)});

routes.get("/alldata" , async (req, res) => { 
    try {
        const foodDatas = await Data.find({})
        res.send(foodDatas);
        console.log(foodDatas)
    } catch (error){
        res.status(500).json({
            Error: error
        })
    }
});
```

This is my front-end (Reactjs) code

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/alldata')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data) 
}).catch (err => {
  console.log(err)
})
      }
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, [])
```

All these don't work it give me Error 404 page with data: undefined

Comment: where are you defining your "/allData" route ?

Comment: I will add it .

Answer (score 0):

did you configure the cors in the app file?

if don't, please install cors.
and add:

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

also:

```
app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "*",
    })
  );
```

Note:
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources

Comment: I added it to my file and it didn’t work till now

Comment: Can you please share your server code with Codesandbox

Comment: Yes, of course, this is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/github/naifah-39/Axois-Error